# flip between an img and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add animation so when I hover over my pictures they fade out and another div with text fades in. Just like on this page: http://jack-hughes.com/

But, I have my pictures in a bootstrap container with class of "col-md-4" and every time one of the photos fades out, the others move into its spot.

How can I make something just like the example website?

This is what I have so far, but it's not even close.

```
$(".box-1").on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).fadeToggle(300).addClass('back');
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bribenn/zsL45bty/

Comment: The second set of divs, for the back are what I would like it to flip into, but maybe that's more complicated than just adding html after a fadeout?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `hover`? It will handle both your mouse in and mouse out events.

You can wrap each image with its text in a surrounding div, and use your `hover` function on this div. Also, if you use the same classes for each image/text combo, your jQuery is very simple.

HTML

```
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
<div class="header">
  About
</div>
<div class= "row front">
  <div class="col-sm-4 about-box-container">
    <img class="about-box front box-1" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <div class="about-box back box-1">
       text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 about-box-container">
    <img class="about-box front box-2" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <div class="about-box back box-2">
       text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 about-box-container">
    <img class="about-box front box-3" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <div class="about-box back box-3">
       text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.about-box-container').hover(
function() {
    $(this).find('.front').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.back').fadeIn(300);
    });
},
function() {
    $(this).find('.back').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.front').fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

)

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29159/)

Comment: looks great there, but it's still not working for me. I have 3 images in a row and if I hover over one, the other images take over it's place. Then it's just a hot mess.

Comment: @Bribenn Here is a JSFiddle with your code. I made a few changes, notably moving the text into divs with their image and moved your `col-md-4` to the `about-box-container` instead of each image and each text. For the sake of the fiddle, I also changed your `col-md-4` to `col-sm-4`. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29159/

Comment: I updated my answer with the new jsfiddle and code from it.

Comment: that doesn't really work...the images are jumping up to take the place of the other.

Comment: On the JSFiddle? For me it works just like the website you linked to. I did add a bit of CSS as well, perhaps you missed that as I forgot to mention it.

Comment: When I made the screen bigger it worked. I'm going to try to put this into my project and see if it works. If not, I'm jumping off the nearest bridge. :p

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's fade effects set element's display property to 'none', and its place is freed to use for other elements. Try to use *opacity* and *:hover* without any JS (actually, this is what is done at http://jack-hughes.com):

CSS:

```
.test {
  position: relative;
}

.test img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.test .test2 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.test .test2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

here is updated plunker based on @Tricky12's HTML: https://plnkr.co/edit/pGYckIcRDPZKS7Ma4vSQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, Andriy! This solution worked for me. The text divs are not in line with the pictures though. They are all the way to the left. I tried to add "justify-content: space-around", but it didn't change anything. any ideas?

Comment: Bootstrap's *col-md-4* class adds 15px of padding, so I modified *left* rule from 0 to 15 px, please check my updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pGYckIcRDPZKS7Ma4vSQ?p=preview, I added bootstrap libs there as well

Comment: That fixed it! That feels like a work around though instead of the proper way to do it. Thanks for helping me through the struggle!! :D